# Search and play YouTube videos on Android app

Tags: android, search, youtube, youtube-api

I am planning on developing an app similar to Snaptube, where a user can search and stream videos on the app just like YouTube. The question is, does YouTube allow for such applications, and how would I go about it in terms of the searching functionality since most tutorials show how just to play videos embedded to the app through a link in methods such as recycler view or web view? Hope I am clear as can be, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube as an API that is specifically designed to search Videos on their plattform. You can retrieve the found videos and embedd them in your app, so the user can watch the content. YouTube allows such applications.

See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list for an API (JAVA) Example of how to search Videos on Youtube. There are Android Libraries that help you with that. They can be found here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/ and here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/android.